# How do I make a Digital ERC20 Tokens with a 10% reward payout to an external Metamask address account for marketing? With an automatic paysplitter

Tags: inheritance, solidity, contract, erc20, openzeppelin

How do I make a Digital ERC20 Tokens with a 10% reward payout to an external Metamask address account for marketing? With an automatic paysplitter via pull-payment and using Reentrancy Guards as a way to send four different private developers a equal share in different external eth wallets? I am trying to use openzeppelin smart contract but I am new to Solidity and I am still not yet sure how to put in my information on the smart contract to fit towards my token or how Inheritance works so I can compile in Remix with no bugs….please help. This what I have sofar.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, here with "commissionWallet" being the wallet receiving the fees :

```
function invest(address referrer, uint8 plan) public payable {
    uint256 fee = msg.value.mul(PROJECT_FEE).div(PERCENTS_DIVIDER);
    commissionWallet.transfer(fee);
    emit FeePayed(msg.sender, fee);
```